# MPPT controller or charger into battery mangement IC?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-charge-controller, mppt, lifepo4

Is it possible to add an MPPT controller (or charger?) upstream of a battery management IC that lacks solar input, as a means of supporting a solar power source?

I'm finding battery management ICs selection to be fairly limited when solar MPPT input is specified as a requirement, given my other requirements, so I'm considering adding it with separate circuitry.

Ultimately my goals are:

- 2 cell LiFePO4 (~60AH capacity)
- up to 8A charge current
- support both 15VDC and solar MPPT input, draw from whichever is available
- coulomb counting to track battery state of charge in MCU

Datasheet for the panels used:
https://ca.renogy.com/content/RNG-50D-SS-G3%20Datasheet.pdf